# iCloud : Data stored with the same key are different on each device

Tags: objective-c, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

When I try to store data on iCloud like this :

```
    // Update data on the iCloud
    [ iCloudStore setData:iCloudData forKey:@"TheKey" ];
    [ iCloudStore synchronize ];
```

And when I verify the content on my iPhone, data have changed with success.

Then, when I launch the app on my iPad :

- App is notified by iCloud that there is changes
- and when I try to read value like this :

  ```
  NSData * iCloudData = [ [ NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore ] dataForKey:@"TheKey" ];
  ```

Data are not the data that I previously saved with my iPhone! iCloud contains a very old version of my data.

So, I decided to remove iCloud data from my iPad like this :

```
        [ [ NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore ] setObject:[NSData data] forKey:@"TheKey" ];
        [ [ NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore ] synchronize ];
        [ [ NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore ] removeObjectForKey:@"TheKey" ];
        [ [ NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore ] synchronize ];
```

And after that, iCloud appears to be empty (iCloud data are nil after the last synchronization).

But after restarting the app on my iPad, iCloud still contains a very old version of my data.

Whereas my iPhone, which is notified by iCloud on start, contains the good values for the key @"TheKey".

My app is universal, so iCloud's parameters are identical on both devices.

I store user's binary encrypted data on that key. These data are used to synchronize all user devices.

I don't want to save a file with iCloud Drive because I don't want to give the possibility to the user to access to this file by using an other application or by going to www.iCloud.com

On all my devices, I use the same iCloud account.

Many thanks for your help.